# How do I remove or clean the glitters from my skin?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

Generally during birthday bashes or similar events, There are more possibilities that glitters stick to my hands, face and even all over the body after the event. Also I have this experience while doing some glitters based crafts works.

Regardless of whether the glitter is thrown like a powder directly or applied like spray, it is difficult to remove them from skin.

These glitters stuck in my skin spreads across the entire home, couch, mattress, i.e. wherever I go.

Usually I wipe with wet napkin and wash my skin with with water vigorously, but it is not as effective to remove completely. I have also tried to use tapes but this will rip out hair, as well.

How do I remove the glitters neatly from my skin?

Comment: Could you add a link to what "glitter" you mean?

Comment: I found being a man and sucking it up really, really helps. Glitter in your beard is a sign that your as manly as it gets, but still willing to make childish gifts, or attend parties for people who love glitter, and are comfortable identifying your manliness with reflective pieces of plastic dust. 'Murica. Hell yes. - a note from man land

Comment: According to the theory of glitter non-conservation, you can never get rid of it: http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=4086

Comment: You could stop going to strip clubs

Answer (score 18):

If I ever get glitter on me and wiping it off doesn't work, I use play dough. When you push the play dough across your skin, it picks up the glitter. It's safe, easy and can even be used to clean glitter off of the furniture in your house too.

Answer (score 11):

Try a lint roll. Made to tidy slacks and such, it may work very well for the glitter. Can be found at most food stores, drug stores, Walmart etc., for around four or five bucks. [lint roller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjU89.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, This is the first time I am coming across this lint roller. Never heard of this before in India :(. I am not sure I will get this one in India, I have to check. Also I saw lint roller is for removing the things from fabric isn't, how well will it work on skins.

Comment: it should be okay on skin, its just tacky paper, about the same tacky as a post it

Comment: A lint roller is also very similar to the tape solution OP has already tried, but generally not as strong - Try using your tape to clean the glitter off your clothing first, and then maybe it wouldn't be as "sticky" and you could safely use it on yourself while still being able to pick up the glitter.

Comment: @JoachinJoseph I prefer a lint roller for glitter. It is simple to use, inexpensive, and covers a lot of surface area quickly.

Answer (score 4):

**This may work:**

- First brush them off yourself, the idea is to get as many of these things off as possible. Because water can make them even more sticky in some cases use a dry brush or cloth.  Even rubbing your hand across your body to get them off will work for the brunt of them.
- Getting a shop vac or nozzle attachment for your vacuum cleaner can help you use that to suck all the glitter off. Alternate rubbing with the cloth gently to loosen the particles and then sucking with the nozzle to remove them. This step is really good for when it is thrown like a powder.
- You should be almost clean now. Get a good soap that is really foamy and soap up with it. This method should remove the dry glitter, if it was sticky then see the alternative step. The idea is to get a really foamy soap that disconnects the adhered glitter and lets it fall away, dish soap is not advisable as it dries the skin out to fast, but some bubble baths and shampoos may help

***Alternative Method:***

To loosen sticky bonds try lemon juice and baking soda as a scrub, rubbing alcohol, or even vinegar. Using oil after the acid scrub helps to moisturise the skin and clean off any remaining glitter, then doing a scrub again helps. Remember to let the oil stay on the skin for a while.

---

***As the other answer suggests a lint roller may help. However, here are some methods to create a cheap Lint Roller.***

- Using Masking Tape or similiar. Rub this across your body, but a lint roller is usually different and this may pull hair. If you dab with it that works better. Also, rub the tape against something else to lessen the effect and then it will pull hair less and in some cases not at all.

**Tips:**

- Clean from top to bottom and when touching a clean area make sure no glitter is on your hands. This way no contamination results and no glitter falls back onto your body.
- Soaking in a tub for step 3 while rubbing down with a cloth or brush(is better) helps clean it off.

**Additional Info**

[Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081101162637AAZGuLr)

I have never used this, so be aware that this may not work and this may be Yahoo Answers saying crazy things again. Also, it is not advisable to put nail polish remover on your skin.

From the User Replace:

> Try WD-40 or rubbing alcohol.

From the User Amelia:

> Try taking a cotton ball soaked with nail polish remover and soak the
>   glitter directly for about 30 seconds or longer, that should break it
>   down

So taking from that answer a strong acid like vinegar or maybe even a chemical like rubbing alcohol should work like I said.

Answer (score 2):

All, of these solutions either involve time, money, or acid. All you have to do is put some olive oil on your skin, and wash it off. It is that easy.

Comment: Olive oil also cost money, rubbing it and washing it also take time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if you use Glad Press and Seal, it removes glitter from any surface. Just cut off a sheet of it and wipe the flat sheet against the surface using the sticky side of the wrap. It takes care of it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I found that rubbing baby powder on your skin helps glitter wipe off. The bits of sweat/oils make the glitter stick. The same trick works for sand from the beach.